# Can I set the content of a Label to a Binding Expression AND a static value?

Tags: wpf, binding, label

Is there a way to set a Label's `Content` property to both a Binding Expression AND a static string value? I want to be able to display something like this:

```
"Current Value: [Value From Binding]"
```

I was thinking something like this would work, but apparently it doesn't:

```
<Label Content="Current Value: {Binding ElementName=SomeTextBox, Path=Content}"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5 SP1, you can use  the [ContentStringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx):

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=SomeTextBox, Path=Content}" ContentStringFormat="Current Value: {0}" />
```